# New look on /users page?

Tags: bug, site-redesign

If you go to [`https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users`](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users) there seems to be a new look on those buttons (which is **very** ugly IMO)

[image]

Is this a mistake, if not, can we change what they look like (I liked the old ones better)

---

And on meta:

[image]

Comment: I checked a few random other sites (including betas) and they don't seem to have this issue.

Comment: It's part of the upcoming responsive design, and yes the styling is.... off. See [New? Buttons on “Users” page behave differently than each other](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310878/307988)

Comment: It doesn't look as bad on Meta, much worse on the main site. (the gray around it and all)

Comment: indeed, there'll be whole new design/"theming" coming soon so expect lots of things to be changing for a while

Comment: If anyone hasn't seen yet: [Ch-ch-ch-changes: Left nav, responsive design, & themes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307862/307988)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They seem to have fixed it now and placed it back to the old normal look:

[image]

And on meta:

[image]